# Update stored procedure not compiling in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that updates the value of a field on a table in a MySql Database. I keep getting an error when attempting to run the query. Below is the error I get and the stored procedure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Query: CREATE DEFINER=`YHI`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_ore_prices`( IN veldspar_isk decimal(10,2) ) BEGIN Update Ore_Ice_Prices SET( veldspa...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
    veldspar_isk = veldspar,

);
END' at line 6
```

query:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 USE `YHI`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_ore_prices`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`YHI`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_ore_prices`(
IN veldspar_isk DECIMAL(10,2)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Ore_Ice_Prices
SET(
    veldspar = veldspar_isk,

);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ref: [**13.2.11 UPDATE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)  You've got a spurious comma and unnecessary parens in the UPDATE statement. A potentially larger issue is that the UPDATE statement will update all rows in the table; it's not invalid to do that, but it's not a usual pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
UPDATE Ore_Ice_Prices
SET(
    veldspar = veldspar_isk,

);
```

to

```
UPDATE Ore_Ice_Prices
SET veldspar = veldspar_isk;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `YHI`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_ore_prices`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`YHI`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_ore_prices`(
IN veldspar_isk DECIMAL(10,2)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Ore_Ice_Prices SET veldspar = veldspar_isk;
END$$
```

Comment: That is exactly what my stored procedure says and it isn't working. see the error message.

Comment: in your code you have a comma `veldspar = veldspar_isk,`

Comment: I removed that after I tried your query. I am still getting the same issue. Any ideas?